Is there a formal reason to allow free variables in formulas?
A lot of presentations of predicate logic allow free variables in formulas and then add an axioms or rule of inference that lets you derive ∀xΨ from Ψ where x is free in Ψ.
It seems to me that it would be cleaner to define the logic so that there can be no free variables in a top-level formula, and  then for convenience, allow ∀x to be left implicit. Is there some formal reason not to do this? Do free variable serve some logical function I'm not aware of?
In a version of predicate logic that allows free variables at the top level, you could, for example, write

x+y=y+x

but for a logic that doesn't allow free variables in the top level, you would have to write

∀xy . x+y=y+x

Both mean the same thing. The first is changed to the second either by saying that all free variables in the top level are implicitly universally quantified or by an axiom schema such as I described above.
The question is whether there are technical advantages to the first strategy or whether it is just a convenience.

Inductive rule of syntax: we write an atomic formula and then apply quantifiers.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I specified the top-level formula.

What do you mean with top-level?

If the universal is impicit, we still need the existential. If universal is implicit, what means not-P(x)?

It would help if you pointed to examples. Typically, 'free' variables stand for 'arbitrary' objects and allow  manipulation of them that imitates natural language arguments. One could say that they are 'implicitly universally quantified', but when ∀ is used explicitly some additional rules become available, like weakening to ∃, changes of scope, etc. This roughly reflects the difference in informal uses of "any" vs "all".

A "top level formula" A contains a sub formula B, (say). In some elongated proof at some internal lemma level (say) you deal with B. Now is B "top level"?

Note: My comment above is the proof-analogue of @MauroALLEGRANZA s which is the syntax-analogue

@MauroALLEGRANZA, a top-level formula is a formula that is not a subformula of another formula besides itself.

@Conifold, I added an example.

In order to write ∀xy. x+y=y+x you have to first write x+y=y+x.

Old Skolem's primitive recursive arithmetic (PRA) which has no quantifier is a perfect example why quantifier isn't necessary or even desirable per mundane results of model theory of incomplete formal systems such as PA/ZF, especially when studying inner or relative consistency. For example, Gentzen applied his schematic transfinite induction up to the famous smallest countable Canto-nonnormal exponential map fixed point limit ordinal ε0 without being a Platonic natural number realist or intuitionistic/constructive ultrafinitist to prove PA's relative consistency Con^R(PA) relative to PRA...

The answers to this question might help.

@Bumble, thanks. That pretty much answers my question.

It's not so much that there is a strong reason to allow them, rather that there is no strong reason not to allow them. Free variables arise naturally in the inductive definition of formula, as Mauro pointed out, and retrospectively eliminate them would make things more rather than less complicated.
